# How to properly store each answer in the answers table? (getting SQLSTATE[23000] error)

Tags: laravel

I have this cod below to:

- create an entry in participants table with registration_id, ticket_type_, and email and name of each participant. This is the first for and is working fine.
- create an entry in answers table with the participant(s) id(s) from the above step and with the question_id. This second step is not working. When "Next" is clicked it appears:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'participant_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `answers` (`question_id`, `participant_id`, `answer`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (00, , 00, 2018-04-24 19:16:10, 2018-04-24 19:16:10))

```
//first for and is working fine
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
    $participant = Participant::create([
        'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
        'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
        'registration_id' => $registration->id,
        'ticket_type_id' => $request->ttypes[$i]
    ]);
// second for, this is not working
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
    $answer = Answer::create([
        'question_id' => $request->participant_question[$i],
        'participant_id' => $participant[$i],
        'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
    ]);
```

Do you know where is the issue?

**More detailed explanation of the context:**

I have a single.blade.php that is used to show the congress details page. In this congress details page there is also a form for the user select the tickets and quantities of each ticket for the congress. After the user click in "Next" the code goes to the RegistrationController storeQuantities() method:

```
public function storeQuantities(Request $request, $id, $slug = null){
    $ttypeQuantities = $request->get('ttypes');

    $all_participants = Congress::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

    foreach($ttypeQuantities as $ttypeName => $quantity){
        if($quantity) {
            $ttype = TicketType::where('name', $ttypeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $ttype->price;

            $selectedType[$ttype->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedType[$ttype->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedType[$ttype->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
            $selectedType[$ttype->name]['questions'] = $ttype->questions;
        }
    }
    Session::put('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
    Session::put('all_participants' , $all_participants);
    Session::put('customQuestions' ,  $selectedTypes[$ttype->name]['questions']);
    return redirect(route('congresses.registration',['id' => $id, 'slug' => $slug]));
}
```

Then the `storeUserInfo()` method redirects the user to the registration.blade.php where the user needs to:

- enter his name, surname and email
- then for each selected ticket enter the name and surname of the participant to be associated with that specific ticket
- then each ticket type can have custom questions like "Whats your phone number?", so if the user selected in the previous page a ticket type that has custom questions that custom questions are also presented to the user so he can answer

Registration.blade.php code to show the fields to collect the above data:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
        <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="name"
               name="name" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->name : old('name')}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
        <label for="surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" id="surname" required class="form-control" name="surname" value="{{ (\Auth::check()) ? Auth::user()->surname : old('surname')}}">
    </div>

<!-- other form fields -->

<!-- if the all_participants is 1 in the confernece table it should appear for each selected ticket a section for the user 
    that is doing the registration insert the name and surname of each paarticipant -->
    @if (!empty($all_participants))
        @if($all_participants == 1)
            @foreach($selectedTypes as $k=>$selectedType)
              @foreach(range(1, $selectedType['quantity']) as $test)
                  <h6>Participant - 1 - {{$k}}</h6> <!-- $k shows the ticket type name -->
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                      <label for="participant_name" class="text-gray">Name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="participant_name[]" required class="form-control" value="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
                      <label for="participant_surname" class="text-gray">Surname</label>
                      <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
                  </div>
                   @foreach($selectedType['questions'] as $customQuestion)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
                            <input type="text" required class="form-control" name="participant_question[]" value=""> 
                            <input type="hidden" value="{{ $customQuestion->id }} name="participant_question_id[]"/>


                        </div>
                    @endforeach
              @endforeach
        @endif
    @endif
    <input type="submit" href="#" value="Next"/>
  </form>
```

Then when user clicks in "Next" the code goes to the storeUserInfo()

```
public function storeUserInfo(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $registration = Registration::create([
        'congress_id' => $id,
        'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
        'status' => 'C',
    ]);
    // the code in this for is working
    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++)
        $participant = Participant::create([
            'name' => $request->participant_name[$i],
            'surname' => $request->participant_surname[$i],
            'registration_id' => $registration->id,
            'ticket_type_id' => $request->ttypes[$i]

        ]);
    // the code in this for is not working
    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_question); $i++)
        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $request->participant_question[$i],
            'participant_id' => $participant[$i],
            'answer' => $request->participant_question[$i],
        ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `$participant` is not an array, it is an Eloquent object.

Before you create all the participants (before the `for` loop), create an empty array:

```
$participants = [];
```

Change the following line

```
$participant = Participant::create([
```

to

```
$participants[] = Participant::create([
```

and finally, change the line when you create the answers:

```
'participant_id' => $participants[$i],
```

to

```
'participant_id' => $participants[$i]->id,
```

This should fix your code.

Comment: *`$participant = [];`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I think you mean the singular to plural? Thanks for the notice!

Comment: Thanks now its appearing:
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'r' for column 'question_id' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `answers` (`question_id`, `participant_id`, `answer`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (r, 5, r, 2018-04-24 21:16:09, 2018-04-24 21:16:09))". Do you know why? "r" was just a value(answer) to test.

Comment: @joW Yeah check the part where you're creating the Answer: `'question_id' => $request->participant_question[$i],` that last part needs to be `participant_question_id[$i]`